# JavaScript Deferred Object - Running Two Asynchonous Request After the Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a menu that has three select options.  The first select is the driver for the remaining two; they require the value of the first menu item to populate.  However, they are parallel--neither of these two depend on one another, so their ajax calls can run parallel.

My current ste up makes an ajax call for the first menu, and then uses the .then() method to make a call for one of the next menus, and another .then() for the last menu.  This isn't very efficient.  I am trying to figure out how to get both of the submenu calls to run under one .then()

```
    //Get campus list and build menu
    $.getJSON(apiURL)
    .then( function(campusdata) {
        buildMenu('campus', campusdata);
        return $.getJSON(apiURL + '/colleges/' + $campus.val());
    })

    //Build college menu
    .then(function(collegedata) {
        buildMenu('college', collegedata);
        return $.getJSON(apiURL + '/campus-year-terms/' + $campus.val());
    })

    //Build academic terms submenu
    .then(function(termdata){
       buildMenu('term', termdata);
    })

    .done(function(){
        <other stuff that can really be completeduntil menus are populated>
    })

    .fail(console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
$.getJSON(apiURL)
.then( function(campusdata) {
    buildMenu('campus', campusdata);

    // use `Promise.all` to run two parallel ajax calls
    return Promise.all([
        $.getJSON(apiURL + '/colleges/' + $campus.val()),
        $.getJSON(apiURL + '/campus-year-terms/' + $campus.val())
    ]);
})

// result will be an array containing the json data from both calls
.then(function(result) {
    buildMenu('college', result[0]);
    buildMenu('term', result[1]);
})
.done(function(){
    <other stuff that can really be completeduntil menus are populated>
})

.fail(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: `.then(function ([college, term]) {
  buildMenu('college', college);
  buildMenu('term', term);
})` is a nice place to use [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Also just so there's no confusion, mixing `jQuery.Deferred` with `Promise` isn't supported until [jQuery 3.0](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-and-feature-jquery-deferred-is-now-promises-a-compatible)

Comment: @Neverever: Thanks, this was really helpful for better understanding the JQuery Deferred object!

Comment: @Patrick Roberts: Thanks for the note.  I incorporated this into my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all three of your `getJSON()` calls are independent (don't depend upon one another unless `$campus` is somehow a side effect of the first `buildMenu()`).  That should mean that you can do them all at once (in parallel), collect all the results and build the menus all at once:

```
Promise.all([
    $.getJSON(apiURL),
    $.getJSON(apiURL + '/colleges/' + $campus.val()),
    $.getJSON(apiURL + '/campus-year-terms/' + $campus.val())
]).then(function([campusData, collegeData, termData]) {
    buildMenu('campus', campusdata);
    buildMenu('college', collegedata);
    buildMenu('term', termdata);
    // other code here after all menus are done
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Or, if you want browser support that doesn't include array destructuring:

```
Promise.all([
    $.getJSON(apiURL),
    $.getJSON(apiURL + '/colleges/' + $campus.val()),
    $.getJSON(apiURL + '/campus-year-terms/' + $campus.val())
]).then(function(results) {
    buildMenu('campus', results[0]);
    buildMenu('college', results[1]);
    buildMenu('term', results[2]);
    // other code here after all menus are done
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

---

If, for some reason, `$campus.val()` does depend upon the first API call, then you'd have to change it to this:

```
$.getJSON(apiURL).then(function(campusdata) {
    buildMenu('campus', campusdata);
    return Promise.all([
        $.getJSON(apiURL + '/colleges/' + $campus.val()),
        $.getJSON(apiURL + '/campus-year-terms/' + $campus.val())
    ]).then(function(results) {
        buildMenu('college', results[0]);
        buildMenu('term', results[1]);
        // other code here after all menus are done
    });
 }).catch(function(err) {
        // handle error here
 });
```